# How to set the color of a selected option in a select tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to set the color of the selected option in a select tag that has a size of 5 so it acts as a list box.

I can get it working when the select tag acts as a drop down but when I make it a list box the selected option is always grey when I unfocused it.

Here's a code example of what is happening. The first select tag is acting correctly, but as soon as I apply the size attribute, the color of the selected option will be grey.

```css
select {
  margin: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
option:not(:checked) {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option val="">Select Option</option>
  <option val="1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="2" selected>Option 2</option>
  <option val="3">Option 3</option>
  <option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select size="5" multiselect>
  <option val="">Select Option</option>
  <option val="1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="2" selected>Option 2</option>
  <option val="3">Option 3</option>
  <option val="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

After checking on JS Fiddle on different browsers, it appears to be a browser style that is getting set.

Below are images from Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer. Both chrome and firefox seem to set their own value, internet explorer will not though.

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you have to set the `background` property of the `option` in CSS.

```css
select,
select option:active,
select option:checked{
        margin:40px;
        background: yellow;
        color:#000;
        text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
    option:not(:checked) { 
        background-color: #FFF; 
    }
```

```html
<select>
        <option val="">Select Option</option>
        <option val="1">Option 1</option>
        <option val="2" selected>Option 2</option>
        <option val="3">Option 3</option>
        <option val="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <select size="5" multiselect>
        <option val="">Select Option</option>
        <option val="1">Option 1</option>
        <option val="2" selected>Option 2</option>
        <option val="3">Option 3</option>
        <option onfocus="this.style.background='red'" val="4">Option 4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the grey box the text appears in a color other than grey?

Comment: @polydegmon I see the text being black, not grey. You want to change that color in other one?

Comment: my apologies EddNewGate, I meant that the background of the text is still grey, I would like it to be yellow if that is possible

Comment: @polydegmon I don't know what you're talking about. There is no grey background anywhere. In my snippet, the background of select box is white and when you click, it changes to yellow.

Comment: I've checked it in Chrome, IE and Firefox. IE is working correctly, Chrome will have a grey box and Firefox will have a blue box when the selected option is unfocused. I guess it's browser behavior. Thanks for all the help EddNewGate

Comment: @polydegmon I forgot about viewing in other browsers. I'm working on a correct example right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a background gradient in case of multi select like below. You need to add properties to make this work in cross browser though.

```
select[multiselect] option:checked {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, yellow 0%, yellow 100%);
 }
```